# Make detailed list readonly in master-detail grid view in the DevExpress control

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

Can you give me an answer how to make detailed list read-only in master-detail GridView in `DevExpress`? The `GridView.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnEdit` property is null. When I try to make new RepositoryItem like bellow:

```
private void gridView_MasterRowExpanded(object sender, CustomMasterRowEventArgs e)
{
    var masterView = sender as GridView;
    GridView detailView = masterView?.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex) as GridView;
    if(detailView == null) return;

    RepositoryItem ri = new RepositoryItem() { ReadOnly = true };
    detailView.Columns[0].ColumnEdit = ri;
}
```

It returns empty cell in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RepositoryItem is a base class and should not be used directly in your code. If you need to make a column read-only, set the [GridColumn.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly.property) property to true instead.

I would also recommend reading the [Modify and Validate Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Modify-and-Validate-Cell-Values) help article for more information in this regard.